# Integral $\int_0^∞ x^2 \exp(-2kx)\,dx$ not defined when putting limits

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I have this integral : $\displaystyle\int_0^∞ x^2 \exp(-2kx)\,dx$

now, integrating by parts ($x^2$ as first function and $\exp(-2kx)$ as second),

\begin{align}
I & = \int_0^∞ x^2 \exp(-2kx)\,dx \\[6pt]
& = \frac{x^2 \exp (-2kx)}{-2k} - \int_0^∞ \frac{2x \exp(-2kx)}{-2k} \,dx \\[6pt]
& = \frac{x^2 \exp (-2kx)}{-2k} + \left[ \frac{x \exp(-2kx)}{-2k} - \int_0^∞\frac{\exp (-2kx)}{-2k}\,dx\right] \\[6pt]
& = \left.\frac{x^2 \exp (-2kx)}{-2k} +  \frac{x \exp(-2kx)}{-2k} + \frac{\exp (-2kx)}{-2k} \right|_0^∞ \\[6pt]
& = \left.\frac{\exp(-2kx) (x^2 + x + 1)}{-2k} \right|_0^∞
\end{align}

now how to solve this? have i done the integral right? suggest some other ways if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $k\in\mathbb{R}^+$ we have:

$$ I_k = \int_{0}^{+\infty} x^2 e^{-2k x}\,dx = \frac{1}{(2k)^3}\int_{0}^{+\infty} z^2 e^{-z}\,dz = \frac{2}{8k^3} = \color{red}{\frac{1}{4k^3}}.$$

The integral appearing in the middle term is just the integral defining a value of the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) :

$$ \forall n\in\mathbb{N},\qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty} x^n e^{-x}\,dx = n!.$$

Comment: assuming z = what?

Comment: Not really and answer to his questions.

Comment: @GEdgar: "suggest some other ways if possible".

Comment: oh my bad. just forgot about Γ function

Comment: @SidVishnoi: obviously, $z=\frac{1}{2k}\,x$.

Comment: what was wrong in my method?

Comment: @SidVishnoi: you did not apply integration by parts correctly. When evaluated in zero or at $+\infty$, $x^n e^{-2k x}$ vanishes for every $n\geq 1$. Look at the proof of $\Gamma(z+1)=z\,\Gamma(z)$ using the integral definition. It is exactly what you need to apply here.

Comment: ok. got it. thanks.

Comment: This sweeps the issue of L'Hopital's rule under the carpet.  In order to prove that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}\,dx=n!$, one usually uses L'Hopital's rule at the end (not that that's necessarily the only way to do it). The posted question takes the right approach (but I havne't checked all the details). But at the end, the question of where to go from there is raised.  Part of the answer should be: Use L'Hopital to find $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}$ in those first two terms. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

What we usually mean whenever we write
$$
\int^{\infty}_0 x^2 e^{-2kx}\, dx
$$
is
$$
\lim_{M\to \infty} \int^{M}_0 x^2 e^{-2kx}\, dx.
$$
Thus, we compute the integral (from $0$ to $M$) using the integration by parts formula twice:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^M x^2e^{-2kx}\, dx & = \Bigg[-\frac{x^2e^{-2kx}}{2k}\Bigg]^M_0 +\int_0^Mx\frac{e^{-2kx}}{k}\, dx = -\frac{M^2e^{-2Mk}}{2k} + \Bigg[-x\frac{e^{-2kx}}{2k^2}\Bigg]^M_0  \\
& +\int_0^M \frac{e^{-2kx}}{2k^2}\, dx = -\frac{e^{-2Mk}}{2k}\Big(M^2+\frac{M}{k}\Big) + \Bigg[-\frac{e^{-2kx}}{4k^3}\Bigg]^M_0 \\
& = -\frac{e^{-2Mk}}{2k}\Big(M^2+\frac{M}{k}\Big) - \frac{e^{-2Mk}}{4k^3} + \frac{1}{4k^3}.
\end{align*}

Then, for any $k>0$, we have
$$
\int^{\infty}_0 x^2 e^{-2kx}\, dx= \lim_{M\to\infty} -\frac{e^{-2Mk}}{2k}\Big(M^2+\frac{M}{k}\Big) - \frac{e^{-2Mk}}{4k^3} + \frac{1}{4k^3} = \frac{1}{4k^3}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Alternately, evaluate $I(k)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-2kx}~dx$, then differentiate both sides twice with regard to the parameter *k*.